# Is there such a word as staticness?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word

I want to use the word staticness but can't find it on a dictionary. I've seen it though been used in my google search.

Comment: Words are words because people use them and other people understand them. If you use *staticness* and your audience understands what you mean: congratulations, you've created a word. May it have a long and healthy life.

Comment: You probably mean 'statics': http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statics?show=0&t=1421498601

Comment: ...or just ***stasis***, depending on the intended sense. Interestingly, [onelook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=%3F%3F%3F%3F%3Faticness&ls=a) (not really a "dictionary") has ***nonstaticness***, but not ***staticness***.

Comment: Could you please give a few sentences from an article, showing 'staticness' being used.

Comment: Odd that no one stopped to ask what the OP means.  "Staticness" could be referring to the property of being motionless, to the tendency for an article to stick to your clothing, or for noise on a radio (and probably one or two others).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20322/discussion-on-question-by----is-there-such-a-word-as-stat).

Comment: Can you please tell us what you understand 'word' to mean.

Comment: "Staticness" as for motionless

Answer (score 8):

There are at least two aspects to this question: will people understand what you mean? will native speakers regard you as a competent user of the language? You might be concerned with the first and only the first, or you might be concerned with both.

You have formed a word by analogy with other abstract nouns, tacking -ness on the end of an adjective.  That shows an understanding of how English works, and any speaker who knew what the word *static* meant should understand what *staticness* meant, at a very basic level.

But since there is already a word, *stasis*, native speakers (or other fluent speakers) might wonder why you didn't say *stasis*.  Are you trying to distinguish your concept from *stasis*?  Some of your readers/listeners might get side-tracked.

When writing and speaking with the goal of being understood, it's always best to consider the possible effects of departing from the tried-and-true.  Understanding is in some respects like water: it leaks out through any opening you give it.

[image]

Comment: How neatly you sidestep the 'what exactly is a _word_?' bunfight. But I'm almost tempted to upvote. You address the underlying issues, without getting involved in the terminology disagreement. I feel it's sad though that a loose definition of 'word' confers some sort of acceptability on almost any string that a couple of people have an agreed sense for. These things used to be called _codewords_.

Comment: But how does "stasis" describe the noise I hear on the radio?

Comment: That's not noise. That's the sound repentance makes when it's broadcast up to heaven.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've never encountered the string "bunfight" before; but I know what you mean. ;)

Comment: @HotLicks *Stasis* does not describe such noise. What you hear on your radio is *static* (short for *static electricity*). It is already a noun, so does not need to be converted into a more elaborate noun by adding '-ness'. The OP's question was concerned with converting an adjective *static* into a noun - which most people accept is correctly *stasis*.

Comment: @WS2 - I don't see anywhere where the OP said "adjective".  (But then he could have buried a Russian novel in that cat fight of comments and I likely would have missed it.)

Comment: @WS2 By the strict, literal, dictionary definition of "static", "static electricity" is a physical impossibility. It's almost as if the person who named it "static electricity" didn't check with the OED first.

Comment: @WS2 I agree with Hot Licks. My first thought on reading the question was that it meant static electricity and therefore OP is looking for a word to describe the property of staticness - eg the staticness of rubbing a balloon and sticking it to your hair (scores 10) versus the staticness of rubbing a china cup and sticking it to another china cup (scores 0). (FWIW I'd suggest staticity rather than staticness). However a bit more thought, and reading the 'bunfight' of comments, quickly reveals many more possible meanings. OP needs to be clearer about what is being asked.

Comment: @HotLicks the OP asked if 'staticness' was a word. I took it to be asking whether you could form a noun - *staticness*- out of the adjective *static*. The 'static' you hear on your radio is already a noun.

Comment: You could be right, but the confusion (whether it's yours or mine) only serves to support the points I make in the answer.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I have mustard stains on my shirt from food fights of yesteryear, so I avoid 'em, unless the subject is whether "text" is language, and then I wade in :-)

Comment: Hey, @TRomano, is "text" language? Also, do you have any Grey Poupon?

Comment: @Mynamite But you don't need to add a *-ness* if you are talking about something which is short for *level of static electricity*. Levels of static electricity are I think measured as *voltages*. So it would be the voltage you could engender from rubbing a balloon versus that required to stick one china cup to another.

Comment: @WS2 You know more about electricity than I. But voltage would measure the property/quantity of electricity and not the property of the balloon/cup etc.

Comment: @WS2 - We have no idea whether the OP has any understanding of electricity, certainly we can't say that he would understand enough to translate "staticness" to "voltage", if that was the sense he was looking for.

Comment: @Mynamite But the whole point here is that in none of these fields has anyone come up with an existing word *staticness*, nor been able to attach any meaning to such a word, were it to exist. Moreover it has not, so far, been found in any dictionary (at least not the OED). So I think it is fair to say that there is no such word as *staticness*.

Comment: @ Dan Bron I very occasionally use non-words in comments, when it's obvious in my opinion that they can only have one meaning, but still don't accept them as 'words'. 'Candidate words'? Perhaps. But 'bunfight' appears in all the better online dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

The suffix "-ness" is currently an active suffix in English, which means it can appended to any adjective to make a noun, as long as there is some reason for doing that, of course – some specific quality you wish to denote.
Language was invented as a way to communicate ideas, and if you have a clear idea to denote and can do so by using an active suffix, then yes, you can and should do it – but of course check first to see if the idea already exists in another form. In the case of "static" you have "stasis" – but if you feel that the idea you wish to denote is somehow different from this, then go ahead and use the "-ness" suffix.

If you [Google "staticness" in conjuction with the ideas of "painting" and "motion,"](https://www.google.com/search?q=painting%20motion%20%22staticness%22&ei=BiA3Y6CFHKmykvQP6u67qAs&ved=0ahUKEwigoKqj_rz6AhUpmYQIHWr3DrUQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=painting%20motion%20%22staticness%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQtglYixVg4xZoAXAAeACAAdABiAGCCJIBBTAuNi4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) you will see many such examples where someone wished to refer to the quality of being static, and used "staticness" to do so, in this context. And there are many other contexts as well, of course, where the word is used.

Are all words in the dictionary? See: https://www.merriam-webster.com/help/faq-real-words

Comment: Hello, 166. There has been along debate on ELU about when 'wordness' is achieved / recognised by a candidate, and indeed 'non-word' etc is a term applied to some candidates considered to have failed. Productivity in the English language is not an absolute, and ELU looks at usage. Unless a new candidate can be shown to have a reasonable currency in some way, it is not a demonstrable word that can be claimed as such on ELU.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).